# set default value for slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, slicers

in a power bi report, I wanna set a default filter in the slicer. the slicer contains different branches and I wanna set a special branch as default when the user opens the report. can you help me to set the default value for the slicer?  I have search through the net but none of the solutions meet my problem completely. also, I have to say I use live connect for connecting ssas to power bi desktop.

Comment: As per my knowledge, this feature is not supported yet in Power BI :(

Comment: I wish there would be a creative solution for it

Comment: You can apply custom ordering to your list of branch names. Then apply acceding or descending to slicer so that your expected branch name comes first and selected automatically. I did this for current Year selection :) hope you can find your option.

Comment: the branch names are ordered but I don't know how to set automatically select

Comment: You have to make such order so that your expected branch name comes either first or last in the list. Then ascending or descending order in the slicer will select your desired branch. Of course single selection has to be on in the slicer property.

Comment: You can use bookmarks to set a stand default filter button, and another as clear all filters